# $addToSet with subdocument's array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following update query:

```
var where = 'answers.round_' + ans.round + '_' + ans.iteration

Game.findByIdAndUpdate(gameId, {
    $addToSet: {
        where: ans
    }
}, function(err, model) {
    if (err)
        throw err
    console.log('after game update with answer ' + JSON.stringify(model))
    callback()
})
```

and the database structure looks like this:

```
 "_id: ObjectId("5304bc1dcf36941e3adcd3fd"),
 "answers" : {
    "round_1_1" : [],
    ...
  }
```

The problem is the ans object is not pushed into the `"round_1_1"` array (not that I checked that it's not `null`). The model in the callback is the model I wanted to update, just the update does not take place.

My problem is something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760004/mongodb-addtoset-of-nested-object), it's like the dot notation is not working ( even though on the console it outputs `answers.round_1_1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're truing to push it into non-existing `where` array. Because there is no such field in your Model, Monggose newer sends it to MongoDB.

The problem is how you're constructing your query. Try the following code:

```
var query = {$addToSet: {}}
  , where = 'answers.round_' + ans.round + '_' + ans.iteration;

query.$addToSet[where] = ans;

Game.findByIdAndUpdate(gameId, query, function(err, model) {
    // Your callback function
})
```

Comment: Wow! I really need to look up the documentation in more detail!